# What is the difference between client library in snowflake and Snowpark?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Could you please explain the difference between written snowflake SQL queries in Python using python connector client library and writing the same sqls in form of DataFrame using Snowpark.

Comment: Snowpark requires Java installation, for starters

Comment: I meant in terms of query execution, data transfer to client systems etc.

Comment: Data transfer would go via the JVM in snowpark, therefore slower, requires more client memory, etc

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake Connector for Python provides an interface that let your python application connects to snowflake and query data

while snowpark is an API that provides programming language constructs for building SQL statements which is based on Dataframe. like for example instead of writing select statement as a string and execute it. you can use select() method withouth writing the sql query.

snowpark API is only available in Scala language at the moment.

Comment: Thanks. But in terms of actual query execution, the processing happens within snowflake engine in both the cases. In what way snowpark ia better than the former. Lazy execution I understand, but what is the core difference in terms of processing, data transfer etc..

Answer (score 0):

The Snowflake Connector for Python provides an interface to connect to snowflake and use cursor objects to run your sql queries.

But, Snowpark is a new developer experience where the library provides an API for not only querying but also for processing data using Dataframe style programming with language extensibility(java, scala, python).

One can write sql statements and use the cursor object provided by snowflake connector for python to execute in snowflake. In fact even snowpark makes use of Python connector to establish connection and push the sql query. The difference being Snowpark API provides programming language constructs for building SQL statements. For example, the API provides a select method that you can use to specify the column names to return, rather than writing 'select column_name' as a string. Along with this it provides code completion and type checking.

To sum it up, if running sql queries is the only intention then snowpark does not provide any huge benifits over connector.